# Are gravitons real?

Tags: particle-physics, gravity, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, elementary-particles

Is graviton a particle? What's your view on this?

Sence physics is the study of matter, it seems to me forced to believe that the gravitational force are particles. There are no particle called magneton to explain the magnetic force. Isn't it because the study of physics need matter to function.

Comment: *"Sence [sic] physics is the study of matter"* - is *light* matter?

Answer (score 5):

We are in the twenty first century and since the time of Newton, physics is not about views, but about observations and measurements and rigorous mathematical models that describe them accurately and can predict future behavior.

The [standard model of elementary particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) developed that way, in a mathematically complex framework, modeled by group theory, and is described by the symmetries of the cross product of groups SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1) using quantum field theoretical tools. This model is very successful and validated. It described the three of the known [fundamental forces](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) of nature.  The research effort goes into incorporating the fourth known fundamental force, in an equivalent model, mathematically unified, which will include gravity.

The graviton is the hypothetical component, the carrier of the gravitational force, similar to the photon being the carrier of the electromagnetic force, and the gluon of the strong force. ( the W and Z are the carriers of the weak force).

So it is not a matter of view , for a physicist, but whether he/she is working within the standard framework, or is forging ahead with different and probably controversial to the physics community models. This last is not forbidden, but it is not the beaten track. But predictive mathematical models are a sine qua non for physics in the twenty first century.

Comment: Prior to the observation of the Higgs boson, there was great confidence in its existence. 
 Would you say that confidence in the existence of a graviton particle is as strong as the confidence in the existence of the Higgs boson was before it was observed in 2012?